# Limit index values in scipy fitting

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit the following data

```
tau = [0.0001, 0.0004, 0.0006, 0.0008, 0.001, 0.0015, 0.002, 0.004, 0.006, 0.008, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0]
tet = [1.000000000, 0.993790739, 0.965602604, 0.924802378, 0.88010508, 0.778684048, 0.702773729, 0.569882533, 0.544103907, 0.54709633, 0.547347558, 0.543859156, 0.504348651, 0.691909732, 0.351717086, 0.405861814, 0.340536768, 0.301032851, 0.192656835, 0.188915355, 0.100207658, 0.059809495, 0.035968302, 0.024147687]
```

using a summation with the general formula

```
f(x) = $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i* exp^{-x/ti}$
```

I'm doing it separately, I'm sure I can do it using a for a function or something like that but I do not know how to do it. So here it goes

```
def fitfunc_1(x, a, t1):
  return a * np.exp(- x / t1)

popt_tet_1, pcov = curve_fit(fitfunc_1, data['tau'], data['tet'], maxfev=10000, bounds = (0.0, np.inf))

def fitfunc_2(x, a, t1, b, t2):
  return a * np.exp(- x / t1) + b * np.exp(- x / t2)

popt_tet_2, pcov = curve_fit(fitfunc_2, data['tau'], data['tet'], maxfev=10000, bounds = (0.0, np.inf))

def fitfunc_3(x, a, t1, b, t2, c, t3):
  return a * np.exp(- x / t1) + b * np.exp(- x / t2) + c * np.exp(- x / t3)

popt_tet_3, pcov = curve_fit(fitfunc_3, data['tau'], data['tet'], maxfev=10000, bounds = (0.0, np.inf))
```

However, I need to make sure that the sum of the a_i indexes, a, b and c are around 1. Meaning a ~ 1, a + b ~ 1, a + b + c ~ 1

Is there a way to limit scipy's fitting function this way?

Sorry for the noob question I guess

Comment: If I would want `a<1` I'd actually fit `1 - a**2`. If it is `0 <= a < 1` I'd fit `a**2 / ( 1 + a**2 )`. With the latter if would fit a `0 <= b < 1` and `a + b < 1` as `1 / (1 + a**2 ) * b**2 / ( 1 + b**2 ) `, etc.

Comment: @mikuszefski in fact I want it a, a + b, and a + b + c to be around unity

Comment: Hmmm, I think this is not entirely clear to me. If `a ~ 1` and `a + b ~ 1` the `b ~ 0` same for `c`

Comment: I can fit the experimental data with either 1 (a), 2 (a + b) or 3 (a + b + c) components. Then I need to select which one provides a better fit of the data and of course ideally the same of each component should be equal to one to make sure I'm not leaving out any component contributing to the data

Comment: Well, that sounds like: check how many reasonable exponential decay processes are there. A simple approach would be to check the reduced chi^2. That does not require any limitations for the fit parameters itself. In other words, a "goodness of fit" test does not impose bounds on the fit parameters. Hence, I do not get the point of `~1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to fit to your data to a sum of two exponentials and also to a sum of three exponentials. In both cases the fitting is correct only on a part of the range but never on the whole range. The difficulty can be understood in plotting the experimental points with a logarithmic scale on the abscissa axis.

[image]

The shape of the pattern looks more like the sum of fuctions of logistic kind than the sum of functions of exponential kind.

This suggests that each term of the sum might be on this form :

[image]

[image]

Thus the whole function to be fitted is :

[image]

[image]

NOTE : The above is a preliminary study in order to find a convenient kind of function to be fitted. The above numerical values of parameters are only empirically approximated. In order to have a better fit one have still to compute the parameters thanks to non-linear regression in using iterative calculus. The initial values to start the iterative process can be the above values of parameters.